# Combining two csv files if first column is the same

Tags: python, csv

I have two csv files which look like this:
First file:

```
143, m, 933, gt, mr
129, f, 945, se, tk
267, f, 234, kl, tk
122, t, 586, gt, zi
```

Second file:

```
143, 533
876, 676
122, 221
231, 879
```

Now I want to combine certain columns of all lines, where the number in the first column of both files is the same. After processing the example would look like this:

```
143, gt, mr, 533
122, gt, zi, 221
```

Because I want to combine the columns `0`, `3`, `4` of file 1 with the column `1` of file 2 if the number in the first column is the same (in this case `143` and `122`). There are about 3000 lines in both files and many of them have the same number in the first column, so I want all of the matches written in a result file. Here is my code so far:

```
def combiner(file 1, file 2, result_file):
    with open(file 1,"rb") as f1, open(file 2,"rb") as f2, open(result_file,"wb") as result:
        rdr1= csv.reader(f1)
        rdr2= csv.reader(f2)
        wtr= csv.writer(result)
        for row1 in rdr1:
            for row2 in rdr2:
                if row2[0] == row1[0]:
                    wtr.writerow((row2[0], row2[3], row2[4], row1[1]))
```

If I run the program it works only for the first line, but then it stops. Applied to the example I would only get

```
143, gt, mr, 533
```

written in my result file. I think there is a problem with the for loops. It is probably an easy solution, but I don't see my mistake at the moment.

Comment: What you are trying to do is called an 'inner join'. If you have to do a lot of operations like that, you may want to look into the pandas package. This would take 3 lines to do with pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your problem

A `csv.reader` object is an iterator. So when you loop over it:

```
>>> rdr1 = csv.reader(open('file_1.txt'))
>>> for x in reader:
        print(x)
    ['143', ' m', ' 933', ' gt', ' mr']
    ['129', ' f', ' 945', ' se', ' tk']
    ['267', ' f', ' 234', ' kl', ' tk']
    ['122', ' t', ' 586', ' gt', ' zi']
```

you consume it. Next time you loop over it, there is nothing:

```
>>> for x in reader:
         print(x)
```

You could convert your reader into list:

```
>>> rdr1= list(csv.reader(open('file_1.txt'))
```

This should work.

### Better solution

Looping over all lines in file one and for each outer loop over all lines in file two is inefficient. This would be more efficient.

Read both files into dictionaries using the first column as key:

```
import csv

def read_file(fobj):
    data = {}
    for line in csv.reader(fobj):
        data[line[0]] = line[1:]
    return data

with open('file_1.txt') as f1, open('file_2.txt') as f2:
    data1 = read_file(f1)
    data2 = read_file(f2)
```

Go through all keys from file one and write out the data selecting form file one and two:

```
with open('res.txt', 'w') as result:
    wtr= csv.writer(result)
    for key in data1.keys():
        try:
            wtr.writerow((key, data1[key][2], data1[key][3], data2[key][0]))
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Content or `res.txt`:

```
143, gt, mr, 533
122, gt, zi, 221
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use pandas - it's a powerful data manipulation library. First, load the csv files into dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', header=None, index_col=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', header=None, index_col=0)
```

You set index_col=0 for both since you are joining on the first column of each file - by default joins are conducted on the indices.

```
df_joined = df1.join(df2, how='inner', rsuffix='f2')
```

An 'inner' join only keeps rows that are in both files. df_joined will have all the columns (the 4 columns of file1, plus the 2 columns of file2)

rsuffix says that if there are column name conflicts, the columns in file2 will be suffixed with 'f2'. Since we didnt define column names, by default they will be assigned numbers (1, 2, 3, etc.). Since columns 1 and 2 in file2 conflict with columns 1 and 2 in file1, they will be named 1f2 and 2f2, respectively.

As per your question you only need some of them (the 3rd and 4th column, and the first column from file2), so we create a new dataframe by selecting only the columns you need:

```
df_out = df_joined[[3, 4, '1f2']]
df_out.to_csv('file_out.csv', header=False)
```